# Storing Log4Net Messages in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, log4net

I am currently looking for some code or a tool/service that allows me to store Log4Net Messages in a SQL Server database. Does something like this already exist or would I have to implement this on my own? I couldn't find anything on SO or Google.

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: You can use adonetappender to store log4net into sql server database, check this good article on log4net database http://goo.gl/Jf9CkH

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can learn about this in the [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#MS%20SQL%20Server)

Also a good [blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-logging/) about problems using log4net with logs saved in a database.

Comment: +1 for indirectly answering the question, while still providing me with my daily humor

Comment: Gee you are so right, sorry I totaly oversaw that one, time for a coffee I guess..

Comment: No problems, I'm trying remember if there are any things to watch out for...actually, there was something on blog.stackoverflow.com, will dig further...

Comment: [Reviews Edit] Obviously some SO users lack a sense of humour. Probably shouldn't expect anything less with a name like that ;-)

Comment: @si618 hhahahaa loved the original answer :P

Answer (score 28):

What messes with **everyone** is **copy/paste without knowing the details.** **Example**: `<bufferSize value="100" />` That means that it **WILL NOT log** to database table until it hits **100 entries** in the buffer to write to the db table.

**For testing/debug  set buffer to 1**

Notice Window Authentication along with `.` for local

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />    <!--Change to 10 or MORE This is critical , after 10 messages then log to database--> 
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <!--<connectionString value="data source=[database server];initial catalog=[database name];integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=[user];Password=[password]" />-->
  <connectionString value="data source=.;initial catalog=InternTracking;integrated security=true;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO InternLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <commandType value="Text"/>
  <!--<commmandText value="dbo.procLog_Insert"/>
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure"/>-->
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

**Next you will use app.config or web.config  "root" to have it called**

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
   <!--<appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>-->

  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: What happens on early or unexpected termination then to the values in the buffer?
i.e if there is only 50 and not the full 100. Do they get sent or are they lost?

Comment: @Mdev  - I am pretty sure that they are not lost.  I forget how they are stored / retained until the buffer number is achieved.   Sorry -  let me know if you find the answer  - I moved onto another project that doesn't have me dealing with any logging etc..

Comment: I've logged in stackoverflow to give you a +1 :)