# How to use Log4Net utility for logging into database using c#

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

Currently in my project log4net is used to log all the exception, information, warnings etc. to a text file, but now what I want is to log all these details into database table instead of file.
Please help me to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Configuration:

```xml
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="server=xxxx; uid=xxxx; pwd=xxxx; database=xxxx" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
      <dbType value="DateTime"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="50"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="4000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="2000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Code in .cs file:

```
private log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ImportGlobalIPVData));
log.Error("This is Error");
```

But nothing gets inserted into log table after using above code.

Comment: Surely this has been done many times before (and documented many times before). Perhaps you might describe what you've tried and why you're stuck.

Comment: Can you please share the link from where I can get the details, because I have never used log4net before.

Comment: If it's SQLServer, there is an example right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279524/storing-log4net-messages-in-sql-server) on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you can post the link of any example in C# that will be very helpfull for me

Comment: @nvoigt's reference actually talks about AdoNetAppender. The destination is SQL Server(database), whereas the config is supposed to be in your application (C#).

Comment: Yes it is SQL server, I have updated my post with the configuration detail, but now I am stucked at How I can use it to save info, error, warninig etc. to log table??

Comment: You are already sending the log level. info, error, warning are log levels.

Comment: I want to log exceptions in the log table which is configured above, how to write the code for it please explein

Comment: I have updated the c# code in the post that I am using to log the error, but nothing get inserted into log table, can you please have a look at it.

Comment: I got the solution, as I have used `<bufferSize value="100" />` in configuration that is why log are not immediately inserted into table. I changed it to `<bufferSize value ="1" />` and my problem is solved. Thank u all for your contrubution

Comment: What messes with everyone is copy/paste without knowing the details.  Example:  `<bufferSize value="100" />`    That means that it WILL NOT log to database table until it hits 100 entries in the buffer to write to the db table

Answer (score 9):

You can have a look [here](http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/how-to-store-log-in-database-using-log4net/), I think this is exactly what you need.

Note that if you want to use log4net from a client application and write to a database, you might want to consider to put a service in between. In that case you can easily write your own log4net adapter that calls your LogService (fire and forget) that logs into your database (probably using MSMQ).

Comment: Yes, from this link only I am able to configure my code to write the log to the database but I noticed that log table is not reflecting entries of log immediately, Is there any setting to reflect the logs in table immediately ??

Comment: I noticed one more strange behavior that when I save the global.asax file  all entries of log are visible in the table, I don't know what is the connection between global.asax file and database?

Comment: I got the solution, as I have used `<bufferSize value="100" />` in configuration that is why log are not immediately inserted into table. I changed it to `<bufferSize value ="1" />` and my problem is solved. Thank u all for your contrubution

Comment: <bufferSize value ="1" />  worked for me. Thank you !!